# how do I add a line break in a string?

Tags: string, line-breaks, sml, read-eval-print-loop

The question is in the title.

If I do this in the REPL (SML/NJ in windows commandline)

```
val x = "hello\nworld";
```

I'd expect

```
val x = "hello
world" : string
```

or something similar, but I get

```
val x = "hello\nworld" : string
```

although I found somewhere that \n is a line break in SML strings.

Comment: How about `val x = "hello\\nworld";`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the string is displayed, the line break is displayed as `\n`.

However, if you try printing the string, you'll see it as a proper line break:

```
- val x = "hello\nworld";
> val x = "hello\nworld" : string
- print x;
hello
world> val it = () : unit
```

It's simply how the string is displayed, and you cannot make the SML interpreter display it as an actual newline except by printing it yourself.